# Delayed Job works in development but not in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

My application uses the [Collective Idea fork of Delayed Job](http://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) to send email asynchronously. The problem is that this works fine in the development environment but not in production. The jobs aren't failing (I've checked the `delayed_jobs` table), they're just not being consumed. There is nothing of note in the production log.

This is the contents of the `handler` column within the `delayed_jobs` table:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod \
object: CLASS:FeedbackMailer\
method: :deliver_message\
args: \
- AR:Message:6\
```

—I can't see anything wrong there. This is my `FeedbackMailer` class:

```
class FeedbackMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def message(message, sent_at = Time.now)
    subject = 'New Feedback Message'
    subject = "#{subject}: #{message.subject}" if message.subject.present?
    subject    subject
    recipients 'me@example.org'
    from       'feedback@example.org'
    sent_on    sent_at
    body       :message => message
  end
end
```

Finally, this is the relevant method in my `Message` class:

```
def send_email
  FeedbackMailer.send_later(:deliver_message, self)
end
```

I know that the ActionMailer code works correctly in production because I've tested it synchronously before switching to Delayed Job. As I said, I've also run it all the way through successfully using Delayed Job in development.

If I run the `top` command on the server then I can see the Delayed Job Ruby process coming alive every five seconds. How can I debug this?

Comment: Start delayed job using this: RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

John,

While I too used the collective Idea fork, I found that Tobi's script works too. I just need a tmp/pid directory (which you may have) and you get the log file and can cross reference this file with what your error column says in your Delayed::Job.first record (or whatever job it is of course). [Script for running as a daemon from tobi fork](http://wiki.github.com/tobi/delayed_job/running-delayedworker-as-a-daemon)

Oh, and you did restart, if you made changes right? Had to ask.

Comment: I can't explain why, but switching to the original Delayed Job fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

Do you run ./script/delayed_job with the `-e production` flag set?

Comment: You run the fork I'm using with `RAILS_ENV=production script/delayed_job start`

Answer (score 1):

Does anything appear in **log/delayed_job.log**?  You mentioned the production log, but delayed job has its own log.

- [JOB] acquiring lock on PreviewImageJob

You might try making a separate class instead of using the _later() method.

```
class PreviewImageJob < Struct.new(:item_id)
  def perform
    item = Item.find(item_id)
    item.generate_interior_images!
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't have a log file for Delayed Job. Is it a configuration option? I tried using the separate class - it worked in development but not in production.

Comment: Production log directory writable?
'touch log/delayed_job.log'? Mine just appeared when I started up, so I remember.